# SSRS Report deployment without access to the server

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to deploy a SSRS report with my id to the report server, if I do not have access to the report server?
If yes, how?

Comment: What do you mean by "do not have access to the report server"?

Comment: If i do not have access to ReportServer database.